# Generate a random serial number from a provided string of characters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that generates a random serial number from a provided string of characters.

This function creates random serial It has 20 numbers but this function not output random serial and 20 number output why?

```js
var char = "123456ABCDEFGHI76wndixdzsfszfs2009765210ojfngdBNMUOP",
  cenrate = document.getElementById('gen'),
  ser = document.getElementById('seriel'),
  serialLenght = 20,
  i,
  randomKey;




window.onclick = function eee() {
  'usesrtict';
  randomKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length);

  // console.log(randomKey);
  for (i = 0; i < serialLenght; i++) {
    randomKey = char.substring(randomKey, randomKey + 1);

  }
  // document.getElementById('seriel').textContent=randomKey
  console.log(randomKey)
}
```

```html
<button id="cen">Generate</button>
<div id="seriel"></div>
```

Comment: Your function only generates one random number.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by performing a for loop and adding a character at a randomly selected index to an initialized string. The randomization can be accomplished with the below line.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
```

You were only producing one random number, you need to produce a random number 20 times as that is the length of the serial number you are trying to produce.

```js
var chars = "123456ABCDEFGHI76wndixdzsfszfs2009765210ojfngdBNMUOP",
  generate = document.getElementById('gen'),
  ser = document.getElementById('seriel'),
  serialLenght = 20,


  genSerialNum = () => {

    var serialNum = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
      var char = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
      serialNum += char
    }

    ser.innerText = serialNum

  }

generate.addEventListener('click', genSerialNum)
```

```html
<button id="gen">Generate</button>
<div id="seriel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to generate a 20 characters long random string, you must generate a random character in the for loop and concatenate the result in a final string as below:

```js
var char="123456ABCDEFGHI76wndixdzsfszfs2009765210ojfngdBNMUOP",
            cenrate=document.getElementById('gen'),
            ser=document.getElementById('seriel'),
            serialLenght = 20,
            i,
            randomKey;



        window.onclick=function eee(){
            'usesrtict';
        finalString = "";
            

       // console.log(randomKey);
        for(i=0;i<serialLenght; i++){
        randomKey= Math.floor(Math.random()*char.length);
            finalString+=char.substring(randomKey,randomKey+1);

        }
       // document.getElementById('seriel').textContent=randomKey
        console.log(finalString)
    }
```

```html
<button id="cen">Ganarete</button>
            <div id="seriel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add up single characters and generate a new one every loop.

```js
        var char="123456ABCDEFGHI76wndixdzsfszfs2009765210ojfngdBNMUOP",
            cenrate=document.getElementById('cen'),
            ser=document.getElementById('seriel'),
            serialLenght = 20;

        cenrate.onclick=function eee(){
            'use strict';
            
        var randomKey = "";
        for(var i=0;i<serialLenght; ++i){
            var randomSingle= char[Math.floor(Math.random()*char.length)];
            randomKey += randomSingle;

        }
        console.log(randomKey)
        document.getElementById('seriel').textContent=randomKey
    }
```

```html
<button id="cen">Ganarete</button>
<div id="seriel"></div>
```